# Remove link from $title in comments

Tags: 7, comments

I'm using Drupal 7. When I post a comment to an article, its title looks like `<a class="permalink" rel="bookmark" href="/comment/9#comment-9">comment title</a>`.

I need only the “comment title” to be displayed, **without the link**.

I found the code in the comment.tpl.php template where the title of the comment is printing.

```
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <h2<?php print $title_attributes; >><b><?php print $title></b></h2>

  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```

As is said in the file description, `$title` already contains the link, so I can’t change it!

> `$title`: Linked title

Does anybody know if there is a way to print the comment's title without a link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
<?php print $title; ?>
```

You can do:

```
<?php print check_plain($comment->subject); ?>
```

Comment: that works greate! after check_plain only the "comment title" left!

Comment: @user16551 `$comment->subject` doesn't actually have any HTML code. [`check_plain`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7) only encodes special characters into HTML entities.

Comment: The reason for using check_plain is to ensure that any 'special' characters in the subject line are encoded correctly for HTML.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way is to paste this code in template.php of your current theme, replace the word `THEMENAME` with the name of your theme (lowercase of course) and flush your cache:

```
/**
 * Preprocess theme_comment()
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  // Remove all HTML tags from the title
  $variables['title'] = strip_tags($variables['title']);
}
```

Comment: thank you! it warks! don't know why i didn't get it at once)) you can make it even easier, in comment.tpl.php instead of "print $title" just use "print strip_tags($title)"

Comment: It's best to use theme preprocessors, so if your edited `comment.tpl.php` is overridden by another template file/module this change is preserved.

Comment: +1 for using preprocessors! Even though template files do the job, preprocessors work best.